# tomcat not working after configuring spring in a web application in eclipse

Tags: java, spring

I tried to make settings for including the spring configuration in a dynamic web project in eclipse.I did the following changes :

1. Modifying the web.xml file

   2. Creating the spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file for other changes

```
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/classes/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.html</value></property>
    </bean>
```

3. Creating a controller class (using java)
4. Creating an html file for UI

But just after i made those changes and tried to run on Apache Tomcat 8.5,its giving me the 404 error,below is my Tomcat console output:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:29 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:34 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Owner/Oxygen/Oxygen-Workspace/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/InvoicingSystem/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Owner/Oxygen/Oxygen-Workspace/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/InvoicingSystem/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Owner/Oxygen/Oxygen-Workspace/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/InvoicingSystem/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Owner/Oxygen/Oxygen-Workspace/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/InvoicingSystem/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher'
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization started
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:35 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 24 16:50:35 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:35 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 24 16:50:35 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 24 16:50:35 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization completed in 3280 ms
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 24, 2017 4:50:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 14129 ms
```

I tried googling but didnt get any option to correct this .Can anyone help?

Comment: Spring seems not to find your controller (no mapped URL are displayed in the startup logs).
Are you trying to reach your controller? Please provide the source code of the controller.

Comment: Can you show us the files?

Comment: For the dispatcher file i edited in the post above.. the first line reads-<context:component-scan base-package="src">
 </context:component-scan>